# KMeans clustering with [0, 1]-entries feature vectors outputs centroids with entries outside [0, 1]

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a dataset for clustering based on purchase months, available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6pdss4c0q3fznlx4rqj23/product_data.csv?rlkey=0g4w3p59ngn04vdok8d3dtrdp&dl=0). All feature vectors have entries which sum to 1. I did not expect to have centroids with the strict constraint of the unitary sum. However, they should (almost must) have entries between 0 and 1. According to the code I provide below, am I doing something weird or unexpected? I submitted a sklearn issue [here][https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/28634].

Algorithm:

```
import pandas as pd
from os import getcwd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score


this_path = getcwd() + ''
filename = 'product_data.csv'

file_path = this_path + '/' + filename

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

X = [list(group_df['months']) for _, group_df in df.groupby('product_id')]

# Assuming 'X' is your feature matrix

# Now, we have the following datasets:
# - X_train: Training features
# - X_val: Validation features
# - X_test: Test features
# - y_train: Training target (if applicable)
# - y_val: Validation target (if applicable)
# - y_test: Test target (if applicable)

test_size = 0.2
val_size = 0.2
train_size = 1-test_size

# Step 1: Train-test split
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(X, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)

# Step 2: Train-test split
X_train, X_val = train_test_split(X, test_size=val_size*train_size, random_state=42)

# Step 4: Model training
# Example with 3 clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=10, random_state=42)  
kmeans.fit(X_train)

# Step 5: Model evaluation
train_silhouette_score = silhouette_score(X_train, kmeans.labels_)
test_silhouette_score = silhouette_score(X_test, kmeans.predict(X_test))
print(f"Train Silhouette Score: {train_silhouette_score}")
print(f"Test Silhouette Score: {test_silhouette_score}")
```

Output:

```
Train Silhouette Score: 0.9338078873850575
Test Silhouette Score: 0.9395121235047589
[[4.82540373e-02 5.09614267e-02 5.32134245e-02 1.03824456e-01
  2.59398992e-01 2.38517675e-01 1.55693519e-01 1.44091717e-01
  6.28019827e-01 9.73606697e-01 1.16770379e+00 7.88320938e-01]
 [1.70372198e+00 2.09958955e+00 2.44583794e+00 2.37549850e+00
  5.03812743e+00 2.22023340e+01 4.85880994e+01 8.07960210e+01
  1.06434009e+02 1.07835291e+02 5.99978649e+01 1.34812973e+01]
 [2.40384615e-01 7.21153846e-01 4.81250000e-01 2.42427885e-01
  9.65685096e-01 2.40931490e+00 2.50085938e+01 7.47704928e+01
  1.04577344e+02 1.04365685e+02 5.25717548e+01 3.85576923e+02]]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't include printing the centroids.

Comment: But this appears to have been answered on the github Issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 2 looks weird. You are splitting the original `X` again, while overwriting `X_train`. So now there may be samples that are both in `X_test` and in `X_train`. This is certainly not what you want.

Comment: While true, I don't think this answers the question.